# Docker: Shared volume when build

Tags: docker

I have this files:

`docker-compose.yml` (shortened):

```yaml
version: '3.7'
services: 
  php-fpm:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/php/Dockerfile
      target: dev
    volumes:
      - .:/app
  frontend:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/php/Dockerfile
      target: frontend
    volumes:
      - .:/app
```

`docker/php/Dockerfile` (shortened):

```
FROM alpine:3.13 AS frontend
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN apk add npm
RUN npm install
RUN npx webpack -p --color --progress

FROM php:7.4-fpm AS dev
ENTRYPOINT ["docker-php-entrypoint"]
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./docker/php/www-dev.conf /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

I want to use all what building in `frontend` (as I understood at the stage `build` at this time `volumes` are not available) in `php-fpm` container, but I get something like this: `file_get_contents(/app/static/frontend.version): failed to open stream`.

How I can do this? I don't understand very well in Docker and the only solution I have is to move `build` script to `php-fpm` container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to delete the `volumes:` in your `docker-compose.yml` file.  They replace the entire contents of the image's `/app` directory with content from the host, which means everything that gets done in the Dockerfile gets completely ignored.

The Dockerfile you show uses a setup called a [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/).  The important thing you can do with this is build the first part of your image using Node, then `COPY --from=frontend` the static files into the second part.  You do not need to declare a second container in `docker-compose.yml` to run the first stage, the build sequence runs this automatically.  This at a minimum looks like

```sh
COPY --from=frontend /app/build ./static
```

You will also need to `COPY` the rest of your application code into the image.

If you move the `Dockerfile` up to the top of your project's source tree, then the `docker-compose.yml` file becomes as simple as

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  php-fpm:
    build: .  # default Dockerfile, default target (last stage)
    # do not overwrite application code with volumes:
  # no separate frontend: container
```

But you've put a little bit more logic in the Dockerfile.  I might write:

```sh
FROM node:lts AS frontend  # use a prebuilt Node image
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json .       # install dependencies first to save time on rebuild
RUN npm install
COPY . .                   # (or a more specific subdirectory?)
RUN npx webpack -p --color --progress

FROM php:7.4-fpm AS dev
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .                   # (or a more specific subdirectory?)
COPY --from=frontend /app/build ./static
COPY ./docker/php/www-dev.conf /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
# don't need to repeat unmodified ENTRYPOINT/CMD from base image
```

Comment: Thank you! This is not exactly what I needed, because I still need to work with volumes, but I changed the config and got what I need!